# Can't figure out how to make a registration script work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I am a newbie, making a website for a school project.

I am trying to make a registration script work, but it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. I have looked through the scripts, and I can't see anything that should be different :(.

Therefore I come looking for help to you guys :).

Thought that a pop-up window would be nice, so that's what I went for (coded in pure css first, then decided I wanted it to actually work.).

Everything is in the same directory.

I am using Xampp, so I access the main page with localhost/stronaszkolna/main.php

Here is a link to the entire website folder, that I uploaded to Google Drive, so it's easier for you to see: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CXzzpLK-D0mYlIZI5sZDwRErj2FJnHfO?usp=sharing .

Tried putting the code in here too, but using snippet the main.php didn't load correctly.

When using "Code sample" parts of the code were being shown as normal text, so I just decided to upload the whole thing to google drive.

Here is how the table in my db looks like:

[image: db table]

Sorry for not uploading it correctly. New to stackoverlow :D.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just look at 2 scripts - you have a PDO connection but are then, in `register.php`, trying to use `mysql_real_escape_string` - which will likely not be available nor should it be used. I would also suggest assigning the prepared statement to a variable ( as you have with $stmt ) against which you can run a logic/boolean test ( no test evident in code )

Comment: Also, if the `join_date` column was set as a timestamp within the db you could let the database insert that piece of information automatically rather than having to add the date in the sql query

Comment: That was quick :D. So I don't need mysql_real_escape_string at all?

Comment: Thanks! I was using a guide, as I have never used php before. Didn't think about the "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" in the db. Changed it now :D.

Comment: not when using PDO - as I said though it may NOT even be available to you ~ depends upon your version of PHP.

Comment: Can you describe where/what the issue currently is?

Comment: The data isn't sent to the db.

Comment: Working now :D. Turned out I edited the location of one of the files in an old version of the document haha :D